# Can I have locators with C# and Selenium on an Angular2 page

Tags: c#, angular, selenium, xpath

I checked this page http://systemaker.com/angulardemo/ and tried to find locator to the Search field with this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[@ng-model='searchInput]'")]
private IWebElement SearchBox;
```

Of course with `InitElements`, but failed with `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: There seem to be typo in your selector: `'searchInput]'` should be `'searchInput']`

Comment: Test your XPath selector using Chrome and `$x()`, e.g. `$x("//input[@ng-model='searchInput']")`

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for pointing out! It was :(